# Minimum precision SQL numbers

Tags: sql, database, oracle

What is the best way to check for minimum precision with numbers in SQL with Oracle database?

```
CreditCardNumber NUMBER(16) NOT NULL 
        CHECK (CreditCardNumber LIKE '________________')
```

or

```
CreditCardNumber NUMBER(16) NOT NULL 
        CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(CreditCardNumber, '^\d{16}'))
```

I understand this is presentation level checking but I heard it's still good practice to avoid illogical data on the database level.

Comment: This is probably never the case with credit card numbers, but in the general case, wouldn't both of them break for numbers with leading zeros ?

Comment: This sort of validation should only be done at the application/presentation level. Even if a number passes validation (e.g. `4111111111111111` passes a Luhn check, is the right length, etc...) it is not *good* until it has been authorized against a payment gateway.

Comment: An AMEX card won't have 16 digits, FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your function really work as expected as you will end-up having an *implicit* number to string conversion. Losing leading zeros. Maybe this is not a problem in that particular case, assuming a credit card number never start with a leading zero (and never *will* ? — according to [ISO/IEC 7812](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7812) the leading number *could* be a `0` in some corner cases).

However, notice you don't have any benefit here in using the `NUMBER` type, as you will never perform calculation on the credit card "number". So, for that kind of data (credit card "numbers, telephone "numbers", zip codes, ...), I would strongly suggest you to use a character type (`VARCHAR2` or `CHAR` if you prefer) instead, and at the very least check using an appropriate regexp than only digits are part of the string. Would be better to validate the checksum as suggested by @Allan in his answer though.

In addition, even if 16 digits is the most common case, [bank card numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number#cite_note-1) are variable length -- from 12 to 19 digits (according to http://www.watersprings.org/pub/id/draft-eastlake-card-map-08.txt as I don't have access to the ISO official document).

Finally, concerning credit card numbers, you have to remember that depending your local regulation you are not necessarily allowed to store them unencrypted...

Comment: The observation about requiring encryption is probably the most important point in any of the provided answers.

Comment: @Allan Yes, you are right, `VARCHAR2` is a good (better?) choice. I rephrased a little bit that part. Thank you.

Comment: The Payment Card Industry (PCI) is essentially self regulating and uses their own compliance system. The only requirement for stored data is that it is *protected*. Encryption is _suggested_, but not required as the means of protection. The account number is not terribly useful on its own, which is why storage of data like CVV and the contents of the mag stripe is forbidden after the transaction is authorized.

Comment: Thank you @Ben for those clarifications !

Answer (score 1):

`NUMBER(16)` will only allow integers (i.e. if you try to insert '10.1', it will round to '10').

Keep in mind too that credit card numbers aren't always 16 digits - American Express uses 15.

The *only* benefit you'll gain from storing credit cards numbers in the NUMBER type is storage space. Since the digits are packed at a ratio of 9 digits to 4 bytes, 8 bytes will store 16 digits. However, every interaction with the data will require a type conversion to or from text, so you'll have to weigh the costs of storage, processing, and ease of coding.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to validate that the value is wide enough is to check the value numerically:

```
CreditCardNumber NUMBER(16) NOT NULL 
        CHECK (CreditCardNumber >= 1000000000000000)
```

---

However, as @BenGrimm points out, this may not be valid for all credit card numbers.

One way to validate the card lenght per providers is to have a lookup table with each provider that you accept and the length of their card numbers. Again, you'd have to use a trigger to check against that, but it would allow you to verify that the length is appropriate is precisely correct.

---

A better validation might be to implement the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) in a function and use it to validate the column value via a trigger.

---

Finally, to reiterate what Sylvain Leroux pointed out, this should all be academic. You shouldn't be storing credit card numbers in plain text and may even be legally or contractually prevented from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use ceiling(log10(Number)) = 16. I think for a credit card number there are better ways to check though.